# How can I open local files with link to access local files with jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I developed an web application using struts 1.2 , I need to display files within my local system(C:\Testing) in a link format.When user clicks on a file name it automatically opens(no download option).File can be of any type(pdf,excel,.doc...)
I tried

```
<LI><A HREF="file:<%=filePath%>"><%=fileName%></A></LI>
```

or

```
<LI><A HREF="file:///<%=filePath%>"><%=fileName%></A></LI>
```

None of them worked..Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think preventing download option is possible, as it depends upon the browser and user can change those settings. If you have any link to a file which can be opened by the browser, the browser directly opens these files, for others/unrecognizable formats browser gives option to open by choosing program, or to save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to make static link to the files that laid on your disk from web pages,so jsp can't allow you to do it unless your folder or files is inside the web app's folder.

Writing servlets or struts's action to process the download will make it.

Now here is the example about servlet process.struts's action will be alike.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fileName = "filepath";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(buffer);
    fis.close();

    resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"utf-8"));
    resp.addHeader("Content-Length",String.valueOf(file.length()));
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
    resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    out.write(buffer);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```